# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "callkeep"

Tags: flutter, dart, cocoapods, voip

When I'm running pod install, this is the error message I received.

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "callkeep":
  In Podfile:
    callkeep (from `.symlinks/plugins/callkeep/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `callkeep (from `.symlinks/plugins/callkeep/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

When I run the project, the error message I received is as shown below

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone in debug mode...
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: 59HZQ7G7DK
Running pod install...
CocoaPods' output:
↳
      Preparing

    Analyzing dependencies

    Inspecting targets to integrate
      Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

    Fetching external sources
    -> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
    -> Fetching podspec for `callkeep` from `.symlinks/plugins/callkeep/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `firebase_messaging` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `path_provider` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `sqflite` from `.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/ios`
    -> Fetching podspec for `video_player` from `.symlinks/plugins/video_player/ios`

    Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
      CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only perfomed in repo update
    [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "callkeep":
      In Podfile:
        callkeep (from `.symlinks/plugins/callkeep/ios`)

    Specs satisfying the `callkeep (from `.symlinks/plugins/callkeep/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:328:in `raise_error_unless_state'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:310:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:308:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:684:in `attempt_to_activate'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/molinillo-0.6.6/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1074:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1072:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:124:in `analyze'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:414:in `analyze'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:239:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:238:in `resolve_dependencies'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:160:in `install!'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/claide-1.0.3/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/gems/cocoapods-1.10.1/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    /opt/homebrew/Cellar/cocoapods/1.10.1_1/libexec/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

    [!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `9.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.

Exception: Error running pod install
```

To reproduce the error:

1. Create a new flutter example project
2. Add Packages

- callkeep: ^0.2.4
- firebase_messaging: ^6.0.12

3. Copy paste the whole 'main' file in [callkeep/example/lib/main.dart](https://github.com/flutter-webrtc/callkeep/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart) into the example project
4. Run code

Anybody knows how to resolve this error? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

I have attached flutter doctor below:

```
• Android SDK at /Users/troylee/Library/Android/sdk
  • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
  • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
  • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
  • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
  • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
  • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
  • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
  • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
  • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
  • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
     https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
  • Dart plugin can be installed from:
     https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
  • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
  • iPhone (mobile)            • 5bde4016fc4cc9d49f209df573d985f1439d5ef0 • ios            • iOS 14.4
  • iPhone 12 Pro Max (mobile) • 7674A9DB-32BF-4027-BBDC-8FED2DD2008F     • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4
    (simulator)
  • Chrome (web)               • chrome                                   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.77

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by editing Infoplist and adding

```
<array>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
        <string>voip</string>
</array>
```

and editing the ios deployment version in podfile to version 10.0

Answer (score 0):

Hello do you have try `pod update` ?
this command update your pod repo to the latest version

Comment: Yes I tried that. I realised the issue was because I didn't edit the infoplist to enable remote notification. Thanks for the answer though :)